# Symfony before login redirect

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to store the POST parameters before Symfony redirect me to the login page (if i'm not logged in).

I tried to set a listener on the Request but this is not working.
I'm using FOSUserBundle, but there is no events to listen on this redirection.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: which post parameters? we need more info about what youre trying to do please. as well as some code of what youve tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

I changed the priority of my Request Listener to 9.
(Symfony firewall is set to 8).
Very useful command : `php app/console debug:event-dispatcher`

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

On your security.yml file you can declare this

```
form_login:
           // All others options that you need
           failure_handler: redirect_after_login_failed
```

Declare your service like this in services.yml

```
redirect_after_login_failed:
    class: AppBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginFailedRedirection
    arguments: ["@router"]
```

In you AppBundle/Redirection

```
namespace AppBundle\Redirection;

class AfterLoginRedirection implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface {

    /**
     * @var $router \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }


    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        //Do what you want here

        //Redirect where you want
        $redirection = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate(''));
        return $redirection;
    }

}
```

- PS : You need to add use statements

This allows you to do something if the user is refused by your security system and before he is redirected on your login page.

- PS 2 : If you don't have security system : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html